# React Native AXIOS method GET response.data shows null

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

Trying to get data on React Native native using axios method GET and local IP.

Running the URL on localhost using XAMPP works fine on the web.

But when trying to get data using api call on React Native, it's showing `response.data` as `null` on console.log()

**The following are the code snippet below:**

The sign in screen successfully shows the user token and user type on console.log().

*SignInScreen.js*

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, TextInput, } from 'react-native';
import { mapping, light as lightTheme, dark as darkTheme } from '@eva-design/eva';
import { ApplicationProvider, Layout, Text, Input, Button } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';

import Constants from '../constants/Constants';
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export default class SignInScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Sign In',
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userName: 'freelancer',
            password: 'password',
        }
    }

    login() {
        console.log('Sign In Pressed');
        var self = this;
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: Constants.API_URL + 'auth/login/',
            data: {
                user_name: this.state.userName,
                password: this.state.password,
            },
            headers: {
                'X-API-KEY': 'zzzz',
            },
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.data) {
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('my_token', response.token);
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('u_type', response.type);
                    //self.props.navigation.navigate('UserHome');
                    self.props.navigation.navigate('Freelancer');
                    console.log("Login Sucessful (response.data) ===> ", response.data);
                } else {
                    console.log('Login attempt Failed');
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
                console.log('Error Response', error.response)
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

        return (
            <ApplicationProvider
                mapping={mapping}
                theme={lightTheme}>
                <Layout style={styles.container} level='1'>
                    <ScrollView>
                        <Text style={styles.text} category='h4'>Sign Up with Email</Text>
                        <TextInput label={'USERNAME'}
                            placeholder={'username'}
                            autoCapitalize='none'
                            style={styles.input}
                            onChangeText={userName => this.setState({ userName })}
                            value={this.state.userName} />

                        <TextInput label={'PASSWORD'}
                            placeholder={'Password'}
                            autoCapitalize='none'
                            style={styles.input}
                            onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                            value={this.state.password} />
                        <Button style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.login()}>SIGN IN</Button>
                    </ScrollView>
                </Layout>
            </ApplicationProvider>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        marginTop: 15,
        marginLeft: 16,
        marginRight: 16
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    input: {
        marginLeft: 16,
        marginRight: 16,
        marginBottom: 15
    },
    text: {
        marginVertical: 16,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
});
```

However, on FreelancerScreen the `response.data` is showing `null`.

*FreelancerScreen.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import Constants from '../constants/Constants';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

    export default class FreelancerScreen extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                dataSource: [],

                //-test
                totalBooked: null,
                dateStart: null,
            };
            console.log('Constructor()');
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.getAppointmentList();
            console.log('ComponentDidMount()')
        }

        getAppointmentList = () => {
            var self = this;
            axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: Constants.API_URL + 'appointment_f/flist/',
                responseType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'X-API-KEY': 'zzzz',
                    Authorization: AsyncStorage.getItem('my_token'),
                },
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log('Response Data: ', response.data);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Error Response: ', error.response);
                });
        };

        clearAsyncStorage = async () => {
            AsyncStorage.clear();
            this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn');
            console.log('Logged Out.')
        }

        render() {
            const { dataSource } = this.state;
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}> FreelancerScreen </Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.clearAsyncStorage()}>
                        <Text style={{ margin: 20, fontSize: 25, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>LogOut</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    {<FlatList
                        data={dataSource}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => {
                            return (
                                <View>
                                    <Text style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>date_start: {item.date_start}</Text>
                                    <Text style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>total_booked: {item.total_booked}</Text>
                                </View>
                            );
                        }}
                    />}
                </View>
            );
        }
    };



    /*data: {
        total_booked: this.state.totalBooked,
        date_start: this.state.dateStart,
    },*/
```

Comment: i can see method as post in axios , do check once

Comment: the method post in axios is for the SignInScreen.js to login.

the problem, however, is arriving from the FreelancerScreen.js.

Comment: The problem maybe in Authorization: AsyncStorage.getItem('my_token')

Comment: hi @ZeeshanAnsari, I have been thinking the same but still not fully sure. None the less, could you provide a proper way to set the Authorization in order to get the token? thanks.

Comment: can you please post your localhost response with a request screenshot

Comment: [screenshot 1](https://prnt.sc/q6ijv4)

[screenshot 2](https://prnt.sc/q6ilg6)

[screenshot 3](https://prnt.sc/q6imb4)

[screenshot 4](https://prnt.sc/q6imph)

i hope this is what you are asking for.

Comment: and this is from React Native Debugger console:

[rn-screenshot](https://prnt.sc/q6iqld)